# Let $f(x) = |\cos(x)|$. Prove the corresponding Fourier series converge point-wise or uniform and show identity.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Consider $f(x) = |\cos(x)|$ for $x \in \mathbb R$.

I've proved the n'th fourier coefficient $c_n = \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} f(y)e^{-iny} \ dy  = \frac 1 {2\pi} \frac {(-1)^{n-1}} {n^2-\frac 1 4}$.

However, how can I determine whether the Fourier series $\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac 1 {2\pi} \frac {(-1)^{n-1}} {n^2-\frac 1 4} e^{inx}$ converge point-wise or uniformly ?

Here the partial sum is given by $\sum_{|n| <N} \frac 1 {2\pi} \frac {(-1)^{n-1}} {n^2-\frac 1 4} e^{inx}$.

How can I use this to prove $\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac {(-1)^{n-1}} {n^2-\frac 1 4} = 2 \pi$ and $\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac {1} {(n^2-\frac 1 4)^2} = 2\pi^2$ ?

Comment: Use the Weierstraß criterion for the convergence of function series, resp. prove convergence in $C(\Bbb R)$ in the supremum norm. Compare to the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: Hi @LutzL ! I see I've made errors regarding the identities I want to prove ($e^{inx}$ is deleted from both, and $(-1)^{n-1}$ is corrected to $1$ in the second identity).
Can you be a bit more specific ? I have proved convergence using Weierstrass criterion using $$| \frac 1 {2 \pi} \frac {(-1)^{n-1}} {n^2-\frac 1 4} e^{inx} + \frac 1 {2 \pi} \frac {(-1)^{(-n)-1}} {((-n)^2-\frac 1 4} e^{-inx} | \le M_n = \frac 4 {n^2}$$ (this is correct ?). Using this, how can I prove the identities ? I would be grateful for help !

Comment: For the last question, looks like you should use (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_theorem)

Comment: How would you apply it in this case? I dont know the sum function ?

Comment: The upper bound is strange, where did the $\pi$ go? You can also directly use $$\frac1{n^2-\frac14}=\frac1{n-\frac12}-\frac1{n+\frac12}$$ to obtain an upper bound that is a telescoping series. And you know the sum function, since $f$ is continuous and piecewise smooth, the Fourier series converges pointwise to $f$.

Comment: I've been sitting and trying to get to a result using Parsevals theorem and your hints, but failed. Would you show some of the computations of one of the identities ? I would be grateful - or if you know a similar example I would be happy.

Answer (score 4):

Define $S_N:=\sum_{n=0}^Nc_ne^{inx}$ and $S'_N:=\sum_{n=-N}^{-1}c_ne^{inx}$. Since for $M<N$, and $x\in\mathbb R$, 
$$|S_N(x)-S_M(x)|+|S'_N(x)-S'_M(x)|\leqslant \sum_{n=M+1}^N|c_n|+|c_{-n}|
\leqslant \frac 1{\pi}\sum_{n=M+1}^N\frac 1{n^2-1/4},$$
the sequence $(S_N)_{N\geqslant 1}$ and $(S'_N)_{N\geqslant 1}$ are Cauchy in $C(\mathbb R)$ endowed with the uniform norm. The series is equal to $f$: this can be seen using uniqueness of the Fourier series.

Since $|\cos x|=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}c_ne^{inx}$, the value of $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}c_n$ can be obtained evaluating at $0$.

Parseval's equality reads 
$$\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^2x\mathrm dx=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}|c_n|^2.$$
Since $\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^2x\mathrm dx=1/2$, the conclusion follows.